# How can I use different IONIC CSS margins and paddings

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

i have used always tailwind.css with vue or angular as combination, but now i am working on my first IONIC project and I am asking myself, why there are not different margin classes pre defined in IONIC, like:

ion-margin
ion-margin-2
ion-margin-3
ion-margin-4

and each pre defined class got different margin values (as we can use it in bootstrap or any other modern UI framework.

I have visisted already the official documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities

can anyone give me a hint here, to avoid writing many own classed in my style guide files.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, ionic's default styling is aiming to [match that of the host system](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/basics#platform-standards) - iOS or Material Design. (It defaults to MD styling when running on web/PWA.) So in that context, there is no need to offer different values as they would, by definition, no longer match the platform defaults.

That said, there's nothing to stop you from defining your own margin values as SASS or CSS variables and using them to override Ionic's CSS properties for the required component(s) either globally or scoped by page/component.